# Adding and multiplying values of a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with multiple columns and rows. The rows are supposed to be summed up based on the unique value in a column. I tried .groupby but I want to retain the whole dataset and not just summed up columns based on one unique column. I further need to multiple these individual columns(values) with another column.

For example:

```
id    A    B    C    D    E    
11    2    1    2    4    100
11    2    2    1    1    100
12    1    3    2    2    200
13    3    1    1    4    190
14    Nan  1    2    2    300
```

I would like to sum up columns `B`, `C` & `D` based on the unique `id` and then multiply the result by column `A` and `E` in a new column `F`. I do not want to sum up the values of column `A` & `E`

I would like the resultant dataframe to be something like this, which also deals with NaN and while calculating skips the NaN value and moves onto further calculation:

```
id    A    B    C    D    E    F
11    2    3    3    5    100  9000
12    1    3    2    2    200  2400
13    3    1    1    4    190  2280
14    Nan  1    2    2    300  1200
```

If the above is unachievable then I would like something as, where the rows are same but the calculation is what I have stated above based on the same `id`:

```
id    A    B    C    D    E    F
11    2    3    3    5    100  9000
11    2    2    1    1    100  9000
12    1    3    2    2    200  2400
13    3    1    1    4    190  2280
14    Nan  1    2    2    300  1200
```

My logic earlier was to apply groupby on the columns B, C, D and then multiply but that is not working out for me. If the above dataframes are unachieavable then please let me know how can i perform this calculation and then merge/join the results with the original file with just `E` column.

Comment: Your numbers in your first output example do not match the logic you described. Shouldn't the first row be `id=11, A=4, B=3, C=3, D=5, E=200, F=9000`? Alternatively, if you really don't want to add the values of `A` and `E` per each `id`, how to you select which value of `A` and `E` to use when computing column `F` for a given `id`?

Comment: Could you please explain how you obtain the results in column `F`?

Comment: I do not want to sum up column `A` and `E`. I want to sum up `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` and then later multiply that result to columns `A` and `E` to get values in column `F`.
Hope this made sense. I might be sounding confused but I want to add few  rows first based on the `id` and then multiply all the columns except `id` to get column `F`

Comment: Are the values of `A` and `E` always the same for each `id`?

Comment: Yes, they're the same @jfaccioni

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the values in the column F. What's the actual equation you want to use? Take for example `id=12` (where there's only one row so you don't have to add across the same `id`): how do you get `F=2400` from `A=1, B=3, C=2, D=2, E=200`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first sum *verticaly* the columns B, C and D for common id, then take the *horizontal* product:

```
result = df.groupby('id').agg({'A': 'first', 'B':'sum', 'C': 'sum', 'D': 'sum', 
                               'E': 'first'})
result['F'] = result.fillna(1).astype('int64').agg('prod', axis=1)
```

It gives:

```
      A  B  C  D    E     F
id                         
11  2.0  3  3  5  100  9000
12  1.0  3  2  2  200  2400
13  3.0  1  1  4  190  2280
14  NaN  1  2  2  300  1200
```

Beware: id is the index here - use `reset_index` if you want it to be a normal column.

Comment: If i would like to retain the same number of rows as the question but with this result, how would that be possible?